# how to compile Protobuf and Curve25519 php extensions in windows

Tags: php, windows, wamp

I recently downloaded Protobuf (https://github.com/allegro/php-protobuf) and Curve25519 (https://github.com/mgp25/curve25519-php) and I have been trying to get information on how i can compile or access already compiled dll's for use in my wamp server. Anyone had any luck compiling these extensions in windows?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- Download the zip-files: https://github.com/mgp25/curve25519-php/tree/master/bin/win-php5.6
- Unzip
- Move the dlls to the php/ext folder
- Then edit `php.ini` and add these two lines:

  ```
  extension=php_protobuf_ts.dll
  extension=php_curve25519_ts.dll
  ```
- restart the server

Just tried it with xampp and it seems to work.